# Apache Tomcat 9_M9 or 9_M25 High CPU

Tags: apache, rest, jersey, cpu-usage, tomcat9

I'm using Tomcat 9_M9 and 9_M25, later it goes to more than 100% CPU usage. For what reason don't know. Hereby list the usage components on it. If anybody knows the reason and solution share yours. Really helpful for me.

1. RESTful API - Jersey
2. IOS Push Notification - 3rd party library
3. Android Push Notification

Comment: I would advice taking a Thread Dump for your Tomcat Process to see which thread is looping/consuming resources. You can use JConsole JVisualVM to perform the same.

Comment: @piy26 - I used jmap, jstack and jcmd. In that most of the threads in waiting state and I checked that on internet (people are telling that threads are waiting for a job its not an issue). I checked whether my objects are hanging on it but not like that. I don't know how to take thread dump using jconsole and jvisualVM (service tomcat is running in linux server).